# CSS Drop down list being contained and cut off inside of div

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.Net MVC application in which one screen displays a list of cards to the user. These are not bootstrap cards, I have made them myself and am just referring to them as cards. In the top right corner of each card there is a `...` that when you click should open a box containing `Edit, Details, and Delete`. However, the box that contains those should extend beyond the border of the cards but this isn't happening and thus the box gets cut off.

This is what it should look like: [image: desired result]

But this is what it currently looks like:[image: result]

Here is the HTML and CSS for both:

### HTML for working example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Draft App</title>
        <!--            CSS RESET           -->
        <link href="css/reset.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
        <!--            BOOTSTRAP           -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <!--            CUSTOM CSS          -->
        <link href="css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">  
    </head>
    
    <body>
    
        <!--                Card              -->

        <div class="container card-border text-center pb-3">
            <div class="row top-bg">
                <div class="col-md-11">
                    <h2 class="num-align white-text py-2">1</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1">
                    <div class="dropdown text-right">
                        <h1 class="text-right" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        ...
                        </h1>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><img src="img/edit.png" class="det-icon"> Edit</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><img src="img/details.png" class="det-icon"> Details</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><img src="img/delete.png" class="det-icon"> Delete</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row pt-3">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <h6>Employee Name:</h6>
                    <p>Cole Perry</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <h6>Encova ID:</h6>
                    <p>34563456</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <h6>Injury Date:</h6>
                    <p>5/15/2020 12:00:00 AM</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <h6>Organization Number:</h6>
                    <p>4</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <h6>Injury Type:</h6>
                    <p>CTS</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <h6>Status:</h6>
                    <p>Active</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary ml-auto mr-5">Work</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        

 
        <!--            BOOTSTRAP JQUERY           -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <!--            BOOTSTRAP POPPER          -->
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <!--            BOOTSTRAP JS           -->
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-+YQ4JLhjyBLPDQt//I+STsc9iw4uQqACwlvpslubQzn4u2UU2UFM80nGisd026JF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

### CSS for working example

```
/* ---------------------------------------- ALL ---------------------------------------- */



/* ---------------------------------------- INDEX ---------------------------------------- */

/* CARD */

.card-border {
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    border-radius: 2rem;
    width: 40%;
}

.num-align {
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 6rem;
}

.det-icon {
    width: 2rem;
}

.top-bg {
    background-color: #808080;
    border-top-left-radius: 2rem;
    border-top-right-radius: 2rem;
}

.white-text {
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

### HTML for mine

```
<!--                Cards              -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4 workCards">
            <div class="row top-bg">
                <div class="col-md-11">
                    <h2 style="text-align: center;">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ID)</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1">
                    <div class="dropdown text-right">
                        <h1 class="text-right" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            ...
                        </h1>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="@Url.Action("Edit", "WC_Inbox", new { id = item.ID })"><img src="~/Images/edit.png" class="det-icon"> Edit</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="@Url.Action("Details", "WC_Inbox", new { id = item.ID })"><img src="~/Images/details.png" class="det-icon"> Details</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="@Url.Action("Delete", "WC_Inbox", new { id = item.ID })"><img src="~/Images/delete.png" class="det-icon"> Delete</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
                <br />
                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <b>Employee Name:</b>
                        <p>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Employee.First_Name)  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Employee.Last_Name)
                        </p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <b>Encova ID:</b>
                        <p>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EncovaID)
                        </p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <b>Injury Date:</b>
                        <p>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Injury_Date)
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <!--End row 1-->
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <b>Organization Number:</b>
                    <p>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Org_Number)
                    </p>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <b>Injury Type:</b>
                    <p>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Injury_Type)
                    </p>
                </div>


                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <b>Status:</b>
                    <p>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Status)
                    </p>
                </div>

                <!--Options row-->
                <div class="row"></div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <p>
                            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.ID })
                        </p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <p>
                            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.ID })
                        </p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <p>
                            <a href="@Url.Action("Delete", "WC_Inbox", new { id = item.ID })" title="Delete" class="links">
                                <img alt="Delete" src="@Url.Content("~/Images/smallTrash.png")">
                            </a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <br />

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">

                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-4"></div>

                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <p>
                            @Html.ActionLink("Work", "Work", new { id = item.ID }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary btn-large" })
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
```

### CSS for mine

```
.det-icon {
    width: 2rem;
}

.workCards {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 10px;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border-radius: 25px;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    background: #f2f2f2;
    width: 50%;
    height: 300px;
}

.top-bg {
    background-color: #bfbfbf
}

.text-right {
    cursor: pointer
}
```

What am I missing or do I need to add to mine to get the drop down box to look like the working example? I apologize if this is a simple fix, I am not very good at front end work and trying to learn.

Comment: Try by removing `overflow: hidden;`

Comment: Overflow hidden does fix it, but then the grey row on top extends beyond the curved border. I don't want that, so how can I not allow that to overflow while alloying the drop down to overflow?

Comment: Then apply the background only on rounded container and not sub; see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting Comments:

- I would tag `Bootstap` here for more responses.
- I would post a smaller more specific section of your html.

Possible Answer to Question:

- Instead of `dropdown`, try `dropleft`. I would also remove `text-right` from there as well unless you really want everything aligned right there.

  - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/dropdowns/#dropleft
- If you still want it going right, outside of it's container, what iguypouf said in the comments is correct, remove `overflow: hidden;`.

Other Comments:

- I would separate the `workCards` from the `col-md-4` so instead of `<div class="col-md-4 workCards">...` it could be `<div class="col-md-4"><section class="workCards">...`
- Consider replacing the `<h1>` you are using as the dropdown button with a `<button>` element. This will be far better for accessibility. If you still want the styling to be like an `<h1>` tag, Bootstrap has the class `.h1` that will work.

  - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/content/typography/#headings
- With Bootstrap you could use `<h2 class="text-center">` instead of `<h2 style="text-align: center;">`. Bootstrap has a ton of helpful helper classes.

  - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/utilities/
- You might consider renaming `text-right` as it is already an existing Bootstrap class. Additionally, you won't need it anymore if you replace the `<h1>` with a `<button>` (from the bullet point above.)
- I would replace `<b>` tags with `<strong>` tags.

  - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/strong#%3Cb%3E_vs._%3Cstrong%3E
- Everything from **Organization Number:** to **Status:** should probably be in it's own `<div class="row">`.
- The final row with the work button does not need two empty `col-md-4`. Instead you could one `col-md-4` and add class `justify-content-end` to the parent `row`. You could get rid of that `<p>` tag in there as well as it's not doing much.

  - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/layout/grid/#horizontal-alignment

Comment: Overflow hidden does fix it, but then the grey row on top extends beyond the curved border. I don't want that, so how can I not allow that to overflow while alloying the drop down to overflow? Thank you for all of the helpful tips, I appreciate it.

Comment: @ColePerry You will need to add the `border-top-left-radius: 25px;` and `border-top-right-radius: 25px;` to the `.top-bg` class to get the border-radius back. You could also write this short-hand like `border-radius: 25px 25px 0 0;` if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the overflow: hidden, and apply your background only on the container :

```
.workCards {
    margin: 10px;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border-radius: 25px;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    background: #f2f2f2;
    width: 50%;
    height: 300px;
    /* Magic of css-gradients with breakpoint */
    background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(60,60,60,1) 0%, rgba(60,60,60,1) 50px, rgba(120,120,120,1) 51px, rgba(120,120,120,1) 100%); 
}
```

Set colors you need; if you need a bottom-border add a one pixel breakpoint on 51 and 52px.